# Maximizing the volume of a cuboid with constraints (lagrange) fails?

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Given is the following (translated) problem:

You have $12$ meters of wire.
Try to build a wireframe model of a cuboid with sidelengths $x, y, z$ and maximize volume $V(x,y,z)=xyz$.

Show that this is the case iff all sidelengths are equal.

My attempt:

Using Lagrange with the constraint $g(x,y,z)=x+y+z-3$ leads to:
$$\nabla L(x,y,z,\lambda)=\begin{pmatrix}
           yz+\lambda \\
           xz+\lambda \\
           xy +\lambda \\
           x+y+z-3
         \end{pmatrix} \stackrel{!}{=}0$$

After solving I get:
$$x=y=z=1$$
$$\lambda = -1$$

I calculate the Hessian matrix afterwards and get:
$$H_L=\begin{pmatrix}
           0 & z & y & 1\\
           z & 0 & x & 1 \\
           y & x & 0 & 1  \\
           1 & 1 & 1 & 0
         \end{pmatrix}$$
Inserting previous values produces this matrix:
$$H_L=\begin{pmatrix}
           0 & 1 & 1& 1\\
           1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
           1 & 1 & 0 & 1  \\
           1 & 1 & 1 & 0
         \end{pmatrix}$$
Now the **problem**:

This matrix has eigenvalues $3$ and $-1$, which should mean it's indefinite and therefore has as saddle point/ no minimum or maximum.

Did I do something wrong or is it not possible to solve this problem with lagrange?

Comment: Your bottom right entry should be a $0$, not a $1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, now it should be correct.

Comment: Here the Hessian of the Lagrange function is useful, but the rule stating that a maximum point is characterized by negative-definite Hessian cannot apply in this case. See my answer below (and the wiki-reference about the Bordered Hessian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to consider the so-called [Bordered Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Bordered_Hessian) that is the Hessian of the Lagrange function. Here, at the point $(1,1,1,-1)$, it is equal to
$$H_L=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & g_x & g_y& g_z\\
g_x & L_{xx} & L_{xy} & L_{xz} \\
g_y & L_{yx} & L_{yy} & L_{yz}  \\
g_z & L_{zx} & L_{zy} & L_{zz}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1& 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1  \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

**Since we have one constraint, i.e. $m=1$, and there are three variables, a sufficient condition for a local maximum for the constrained problem is that determinant of the $3\times3$ principal minor is positive and the determinant of the entire matrix is negative.**

It is easy to verify that both conditions holds:
$$\left|\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right|=2>0,\quad\left|\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 1& 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1  \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right|=-3<0.$$
and therefore the point $(1,1,1)$ is a maximum for your constrained  problem.

Comment: This is actually the same determinant that the OP was calculating; however, there is a typo in the bottom right entry.